# ElasticSearch typo handling and matching

Tags: php, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have an ElasticSearch implementation via the PHP client (version 8.3) provided here: [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

At present I use the fuzziness function in a variety of ways. Mostly by using AUTO or a number based on how long a certain word/phrase is. Right now I either use fuzziness on the entire phrase or break up the phrase into words and apply fuzziness to them, like so:

```
[
  "index" => "products"
  "body" => [
    "query" => [
      "bool" => [
        "should" => [
          0 => [
            "match" => [
              "title" => [
                "query" => "audi a22"
                "fuzziness" => "2"
                "minimum_should_match" => "1"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

My question is as follows: is there a better way to handle typos and better match perfect matches?

With the above query it matches "m22" and "s22" better than the "a22" we're searching for, even if products with that exact match exist within the index.

I tried combining two queries, a query which looks for the exact match and boosts the result by 10 and another which searched for the same term but used fuzziness AUTO. Instead I got results which matched with the "s22" and "m22" terms. I expected it to give me exact matches followed by the matches containing "s22"  and "m22".

Comment: Do you use a specific analyser ? Could we get it from your index settings ?

Comment: @Paulo I'm still figuring it out but I think I have the default analyzer. I haven't changed anything specific to my index settings. What I have done is put norms on false on the title field via the mapping.